# DatagramSocket.receive() and SocketException

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a thread whose job is to sit on a DatagramSocket, listen for incoming packets, and place them into a queue for further processing.  Its run method is:

```
        public void run() {
        while(!disconnected) {
            byte[] buffer1 = new byte[FrameSizeBytes];
            DatagramPacket RxPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer1,buffer1.length);
            try {
                RxSocket.receive(RxPacket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle exception
            }
            buffer1 = RxPacket.getData();
            Q.add(buffer1);
        }
    }
```

I have another thread whose job it is to decide when to terminate this thread. 
It does this by setting the `disconnected` variable to true, and closing the socket. 
The idea was that closing the socket would unblock the thread into an exception; the exception could be handled; and once the exception was handled the loop condition would cause the loop to exit. (Alternatively, the `exception` handling itself could set disconnected to true.)

Problem:  The exception thrown in this condition is a `SocketException:  socket closed` which makes perfect sense.  But DatagramSocket.receive() doesn't throw SocketExceptions, and therefore I can't handle it or throw it.

Question:  Is there some way to get this idea to work, or do I need to find another approach?  (Note:  I don't just want to set a timeout on the socket.  That's not a good approach for this application.)

Comment: The approach doesn't make any sense and should definitely be abandoned. It's a dangerous error to release a resource in one thread while another thread is, or might be, using it. (Are you sure you need to terminate the thread? Is it doing any harm?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the flag, send yourself a dummy packet, then close the socket. After receive(), check the flag before processing the packet,